# Backbone using GET instead of PUT or POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I'm having some issues with a Backbone project that I am working on.

I have the following model:

```
class App.Models.Purchaseorder extends Backbone.Model
    url: ->
        base = 'api/purchaseorders'

        if this.isNew()
            base
        else
            base + '/' + this.id;

    urlRoot: 'api/purchaseorders'
```

When I run the following in the console:

```
po = new App.Models.Purchaseorders;
po.set({'po_number': '1234', 'locale': 'Home', 'po_date': '3/22/2012'});
```

it appears to set the attributes correctly. However, if I run

```
po.save()
```

I would expect it to do a POST request to the api/purchaseorders URL. When I debug through the save() and sync() functions in the Backbone JS, it looks like it is indeed running a POST, but at the last minute, it looks as if it is really doing a GET https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL3gt.png

I am a little confused as to why this would be happening. I am having similar issues when trying to do an update -- which should be doing a PUT. I am assuming something is funky in the model, but I have no clue what it could be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess - maybe after POST it is syncing state of backbone model with backend model?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you have in the question (had to call `new App.Models.Purchaseorder`, without the `s`, though FYI) and it does a POST as expected.

What version of Backbone *and* Underscore are you using?

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfunduk/Hqf3t/).